# compute if present Map

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {

    private static Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("Ciao", 5, "Luca", 10, "Marco", 50);
    private static final String NEW_KEY = "New key";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        map.computeIfPresent("Ciao", (k, v) -> {
            map.remove("Ciao");
            map.put(NEW_KEY, 10);
            return v;
        });
    }
}
```

Why do I have to return v inside computeIfPresent when I don't want to? If k and v are not used, can i not pass them?

Comment: You are not using `computeIfPresent` as intended. What do you want to achieve? You _remove_ the value from the map, insert some random new value, and return the old value associated with the now-removed key? "If k and v are not used, can i not pass them?" The point is, you _should_ need them; if you don't need them, maybe you are not using the right method. I think, what you _really_ need is just `if map.containsKey("Ciao") { ...}`.

Comment: I think you should start by reading the javadoc on that method, and maybe a tutorial.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashmap-computeifpresentkey-bifunction-method-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: Why don't you just remove `"Ciao"` and run `map.put(NEW_KEY, 10);` if `null` is returned?

Answer (score 4):

`computeIfPresent` is there to handle conflicts for the same key. For your case, I think you can just do this

```
if (map.remove("Ciao") != null) {
  map.put(NEW_KEY, 10);
}
```

This will only work in case your Map is mutable and doesn't take `null` as a value. Your Map is only null-safe, but also immutable

Comment: Technically, `remove` could also return `null` if the key was previously mapped to the value `null`. Seems not to be the case here, though.

Comment: Actually this is wrong, `Map.of()` will not accept null for either keys nor values. However, since it returns an ImmutableMap, both our answers don't work anyways.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-

Comment: That's what I meant with "seems not to be the case here", but in general `Map` can have `null` values, so just checking that the value returned by `remove` is `null` does not guarantee that it wasn't present.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `computeIfPresent` as intended, and (without having tested it) your code will most likely not work. In particular, the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) states that the `Map` should *not* be modified within the callback function. If you want to replace one key/value with another key/value pair, you should just use `if` instead:

```
if (map.containsKey("Ciao")) {
    map.remove("Ciao");
    map.put(NEW_KEY, 10);
}
```